# Good way to show Application reminder on home page

Tags: usability, layout

I am working on a financial website where people can take loan, insurance etc. I need to display a reminder of sorts when a visitor comes back again on the home page showing that they have been looking at these products or were trying to apply for that product.
[image: The layout is like this above the fold]

What is a decent way to show the same without cluttering but still being prominent enough with CTAs

My idea to put Recent visited elements, in a horizonatal line.
[image: This was the idea to put Recent visited elements]

Trouble with this is, if he's visited only 1 product , this layout does not work as it looks empty towards right.

PLease suggest

Thanks!

Comment: The bottom row of products, is it a list of "all products offered" or "recently visited products"?

Comment: @ Igorek  All the products

Answer (score 1):

> I need to display a reminder of sorts when a visitor comes back again on the home page showing that they have been looking at these products or were trying to apply for that product.

There are many ways to tackle this problem. So here are a few items to consider:

1. If a user has visited several products, do you want to bombard them with the entire catalog upfront? Most likely not, therefore I would suggest showing "recently viewed products" before you show the catalog
2. If a user has visited some products in the past, should we show them an entire catalog? (ver.A and ver.B below shows variations)

[image: Recently Viewed Products]

Answer (score 1):

> Trouble with this is, if he's visited only 1 product , this layout does not work as it looks empty towards right.

Igorek shared good solutions to your problem on how to show recently visited products. However, if the user only visited 1 product, another approach I could think of is use image thumbnail and description.

[image]

It would also present the items in a professional layout since it's a financial website talking about loans, insurance. A short description about the item might be valuable. Thumbnails are commonly used in ecommerce sites but definitely still possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

As for the wording, "Recently Visited" (or "Viewed") would better apply to the singular case, as well as working with plural.

As for the layout, perhaps you could simply center it, so when the items take up less space than the full page it wouldn't look as weird.

Comment: If there is only one recently viewed product, why not have another section in that row with "Other users who viewed this product also viewed..."